# export data from a xml file on sharepoint to sql server using ssis

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have a xml file sitting in a folder which is in a document library on a page on sharepoint. I am trying to extract data from the xml file to a table using SSIS packages.

I have tried using Listadapters for sharepoint and I don't think that works to export data from a file on sharepoint library (maybe only for lists).

I have also tried using HTTP connection manager to connect to the sharepoint online. But it keeps giving me an error saying "connection is forbidden (403). I have provided the appropriate credentials.

This is my first time and any kind of direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use the '**copy link**' feature in sharepoint to generate a URL with authentication.

[image]

2. Use the '**execute process task**' to download the file using powershell

[image]

3. Import the file to SQL server using an '**xml source**' connection found inside the data flow under 'other sources'.